# Can this ethernet cable swap affect my connectivity?

Tags: networking, cable

I have a router connected to a modem with a short ethernet cable (yellow, call it Cable A). I have a computer connected to the router via 20 ft ethernet cable (black, call it Cable B). Neither is cross-over.

Everything works fine.

Then I exchange the cables so I can change the location of the router in the room. Now I get very short network interruptions.

```
modem <--cable A--> router <--cable B--> computer (no problem)
modem <--cable B--> router <--cable A--> computer (problem)
```

I don't see how this is possible. All the network traffic to my computer was going through both Cable A and Cable B before and after.

Comment: You could try turning the cable(s) itself around. When doing so the other 4 lines are used in the cable (with 100MBps). Maybe one cable is defective on one of those lines and turning it around could solve that. Replacing both cables would solve it too :) (With gigabit network connection all 8 lines are used) If turning one cable around solves it then that cable is the defective one (and you might want to replace it if you're ever want to go to 1GB speed)

Comment: It turned out to be some flakiness somewhere, and just fixed itself. So I've upvoted the answer since it has useful information, but it didn't actually solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe cable A is cross-over and cable B is straight-through (or vice-versa), and any of the devices you're managing doesn't have the internal circuitry needed to disregard what kind of cable you're using.

In summary, there are some "categories" which define what devices should be connected via a straight-through cable or a cross-over cable. Usually, modems and routers should be connected via cross-over cables. Nowadays, most of the devices have built-in mechanisms (Auto MDI/MDX), so there's no need to check which kind of cable you're plugging in because they will adapt to a configuration when it's needed. But if not, then communication might be impossible, slowed down or even interrupted after a time.

I'm not saying this is the only reason, but it is a common one.

More info:

- [Straight-through cable](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/i/100001-200000/120001-130000/127001-128000/127838.ps/_jcr_content/renditions/127838.jpg)
- [Cross-over cable](http://digital.natinst.com/public.nsf/$CXIV/ATTACH-AEEE-7KVU55/$FILE/crossovercableGIG.jpg)
- [Straight-through, Crossover, and Rollover Wiring](https://www.computercablestore.com/straight-through-crossover-and-rollover-wiring)

Comment: This is likely correct then the modem and router do not have auto MDI/MDX and the computer does have it. (Also, modern computers tend to the gigabit speeds which requires having this).

Comment: Neither is cross-over. I checked. :)